# Missing Autocomplete in Zend Studio 9.0.4

Tags: autocomplete, zend-studio

I'm working with Zend Studio since 1 week. The last week I was doing stuff with ZF2 tutorials. Today I had to do some coding on an old project. I made a clean checkout via SVN and recognized, that I had no autocomplete. I thought there might be a problem with my project, so I created a new local project, with only one file in it.

```
<?php
class foo {
    public function bar() {
        echo "foobar";
    }
}

$ac = new foo();
$ac->bar();
```

Unfortunaly "new foo()" is underlined and Zend Studio says "Class 'foo' not found". So the problem has nothing to do with the include_path or the build path, like others had problems with before.

Anyone else had this strange issue before or has an idea how to solve it?